# trigger a Batch job from rest full webservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My rest service request will have list of data object .Each list contain around 5000 data object   .Instead of directly insert into DB I want to trigger batch job which will read the data object  and insert into db.This i want to do with spring boot .Sample example I got it from spring doc which will read from excel sheet and firing into DB .But that info not sufficient to trigger from rest . How will trigger this batch job and reading data from Rest webservcie.Please help me

Comment: Can you give more informations about your data, your database, what you already tried...?

Comment: Data is nothing but  JSON input received in the restful webservcie.Those info I have converted java object and passed as DTO to my service layer .My servcie layer will have list of DTO.From here I have to read this data through Itemreader (custom ) and process it and write it into Postgress SQL  through batch job.This batch job and data read should happen when I received rest request . What I have tried is reading data  from flat file and inserted into DB .Link mentioned here (http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)

Comment: any comments on above mentioned problem